# How to access controller from vendor in http\controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vendor

I have tried using

```
$data = BasicFunctions::checkEmailExists('emailaddress', 'Modal_name');
```

I am using my own package **https://packagist.org/packages/jainam/basicfunctions**

It is giving error that **Class vendor\jainam\basicfunctions\src\BasicFunctions does not exist**

Can anyone know how to use this?

I am adding that file using **use BasicFunctions;**

Comment: How did you install the package?

Comment: Set auto loading path in `composer`. If that is already set, regenerate composer autoload file. Run `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate autoload file

Comment: @Rwd I have installed the package from composer `composer require jainam/basicfunctions`

Comment: @CerlinBoss can you collaborate?

Comment: Can you show the entire file? Are you trying to link to the file of that class directly? Can you show how you import the class?

Answer (score 1):

Open your plugin's `composer.json` file and change

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "jainam\\BasicFunctions\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

to

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Jainam\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

NOTE: `"Jainam\\": "src/"` here is the namespace, so you will end up writing `use Jainam\BasicFunctions` in your code.

Then install the plugin and run `composer dump-autoload`.

To test this now, you can directly edit the composer.json file inside vendor folder and run `composer dump-autoload` in your project

Comment: I have updated composer as you mentioned but still showing same error message, also you have mentioned that don't write `use\Jainam\BasicFunctions` so how can i access functions of that class in my controller I am using like this `BasicFunctions::checkEmailExists('email', 'model')`

Comment: where have i mentioned `don't write`?

Comment: Stilll showing error `Class 'Jainam\BasicFunctions' not found`